# How to check what is the percentage of charge in my lead acid battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, measurement, lead-acid

http://www.allbatteries.co.uk/media/pdf/AMP92108_FR.pdf

I want to know how much percentage of the battery charge is left without buying any fancy equipment to measure it.

Comment: connect the battery to an ADC of the micro controller and measure the voltage as specified in  @helloworld992 answer

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a lead acid battery with 2 cells. Luckily, assuming a relatively healthy battery you can get a rough idea of the charge level by just [measuring the open circuit voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery#Voltages_for_common_usages).

Here's a table of values for some rough voltages to expect (computed using value from [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_state_of_charge))

```
100%: 4.22V
75%:  4.15V
50%:  4.08V
25%:  4.02V
0%:   3.96V
```

If you want to go more in depth, I would recommend reading [this page](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/testing_deep_cycle_lead_acid_batteries), as well as the links inside that page. The short answer is "it's complicated", and specialized equipment is probably the best answer.

Comment: Thank you! But can you please explain how did you compute those values from the website, is there an equation for it? Because i might need this technique for other batteries than the one i mentioned

Comment: @Mohdak See the first table in the "Hydrometer" section. Look under the "8V" column and divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want fancy gear and if you are using Flooded lead acid batteries then the Hydrometer could be for you. It measures the specific gravity of the electrolyte. Pure water which would represent a totally discharged possibly beyond redemption cell is represented by a reading of 1000. Sulphuric acid is denser than water. The more concentrated the acid is the higher the hydrometer reading. For example a good cell in a lucas 90AH marine starting battery would read 1260. Precise readings will have some dependence on temperature and battery chemistry. I used this in 1980 after my Lambda DVM blew up and I was never left stranded on my experimental electric bike that was powered by a thirsty truck starter motor. The hydrometer would put holes in clothes that looked like cigarette burns if you weren't really careful. The hydrometer allowed knowledge of impending cell problems which the DVM would not. Maybe the hydrometer was better than the DVM. Maybe acid concentration could be measured directly these days but that means fancy gear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the batery acid itself, a refractometer is a very precise instrument for measureing state of charge.

[image]

Otherwise, you need a multimeter and measure the resting voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a few basics that can give you an idea, there's no flawless and accurate method to determine how healthy a battery is. Voltage at rest is no guarantee. Winny's suggestion of a hygrometer is a good one (it will tell you a fair bit about the condition) but potentially not very practical for battery monitoring.

I have two lead-acid batteries of identical capacity; one was damaged by over-discharge and the other is used but in good condition.

They both measure a healthy voltage at rest, but the damaged one drops like a stone under load and has less than 5% of its rated capacity available. A simple voltage test would not tell the difference at rest, although it would obviously see the bad one dropping off. I measured the capacity using a load tester at C/20 rate, and logging the voltage over time.

If you know you're starting with a good battery then the voltage at rest can give you a basic indication but it's not perfect. Serious systems do all sorts of things like coulomb counting and profiling, but then they also tend to be using quality batteries with well specced behaviour that the system can be calibrated for & rely upon.